# nginx how to have a dynamic order of try_files

Tags: nginx

I don't know how better to phrase that question so let me know if there is a better way but here is what I want to do.

I have an app that sends an html file based on the request url which also creates a cache of that html file in a cache folder so that nginx can just serve the cached file the next time someone visits that same url.

This is working as expected except that I don't want the cache to be read by nginx when there are query parameters. I want the app to be the one to handle the request when this happens but the cache gets sent instead. Here is what I have so far:

```
    location / {
        root    /path/to/site;
        try_files /content/cache/$uri.html @app;
    }

    location @app {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
```

So how do I have the `try_files` bypass the `content/cache/$uri.html` and go straight to the `@app` when there are query args in the url?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone else will probably think of something complicated involving `if` but I think I have a very simple solution for this.

Your application caches files using the URL path, without query arguments, as the filename. If the requested URL has a query string, you don't want to use the cache.

nginx has a variable `$is_args` which is empty if there is no query string, or contains a `?` if there is a query string. You can simply incorporate this:

```
        try_files /content/cache/$uri.html$is_args @app;
```

Therefore, if the URL contains a query string, the path that nginx tries will be appended with a `?` and will not match the file. The request will then pass to your application.

Comment: Shouldn't one simply use proxy_cache?

Comment: @AlexeyTen If you want nginx to do the caching itself, then yes. If your application already does caching or has some complicated requirement that nginx caching won't easily handle, then you would do this.

Comment: @AlexeyTen in this particular case I would need the app to handle caching not nginx.